# Setting up Related List on Console

Tags: console, custom-console-components, feed-based-layout

I am using the SFDC Sample Console.  I have created an Account Page feed-based layout, and assigned it to myself.  In the feed-based page layout I have edited the Custom Console Components to display some related lists on the bottom sidebar, as per the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when I look at the Account page in the Sample Console, when I look at the detail page, I only see the main Account page, and do not see the bottom sidebar.  On the detail page, I do not see the related lists which I marked as 'Hide on Detail Page', so I know that part is working.  Am I missing a step to show the bottom sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Bottom Sidebar(Interaction Log)`, that may be the issue. There is another `Bottom Sidebar` exists. Use that.

[image: Bottom sidebar]

Comment: Even if I choose Right Sidebar, it is not displaying the related lists.  In addition, even if select somethign else to display (I tried with a VF Page) in any of the sidebars, it is not displaying.  It sounds like I am mssing a fundamental step, but not sure what that step is.